# What does this exactly mean?

Tags: c++

Could anyone please explain me what exactly the following line of code produce?

```
i = 1<<(sizeof(n) * 8 - 1);
```

You can assume whatever value you want for 'n'. I am trying to implement an 8 bit multiplication program using Booths algorithm.

Comment: `<<` is called a bitwise operator... you may find this link helpful http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: Reasons for rating of -4?

Comment: @chris not quite the same though, right? His code just gives something with the most significant bit of type n set to 1.

Comment: You're aware that `sizeof()` applies to types, or types of variables? Hard to tell what it does exactly, without knowing the types of `i` and `n`.

Comment: @PeterT, Oops, silly me :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break it down:

- `sizeof(n)` delivers the size of the type of variable `n`. For an `int` variable `n` on a 32 bit system, this would e.g. be 4 (bytes). See the sizeof documentation e.g. here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/sizeof)
- `* 8` -> multiplication by the number of bits in one byte -> i.e. `sizeof(n) * 8` delivers the number of *bits* necessary for `n`.
- `<<` is the shiftleft operator. It will shift the first operand to the left by the amount of bits specified by the second operand (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift); it's the logical shift, meaning that bits shifted in from the right are filled up with zeroes.

The full expression therefore delivers an expresssion with the highest bit representable by the variable `n` set to 1.

Example (assuming `n` now to be of type `char`, and assuming the size of char as the typical 1 byte):

```
sizeof(char) = 1
=> sizeof(char) * 8 - 1 = 7
=> 1 << 7 = 10000000
```